# SKCameraNode functions containsNode() and containedNodeSet() aren't working as expected

Tags: ios, swift, sknode

I was trying to use the new SKCameraNode in iOS 9.0, but I encountered that the camera is always returning false for containsNode() and an empty set for containedNodeSet().

Just to test, I created an empty project with the SpriteKit template and added a camera. The only thing I changed was in GameScene:

```
class GameScene: SKScene {  
    let myLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Chalkduster")  

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {  
        / Setup your scene here */  
        myLabel.text = "Hello, World!";  
        myLabel.fontSize = 65;  
        myLabel.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame));  

        let camera = SKCameraNode()  
        camera.position = CGPoint(x:CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y:CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))  

        self.addChild(camera)  
        self.addChild(myLabel)  

        self.camera = camera  
    }  

    override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {  
       / Called when a touch begins */  

        for touch in touches {  
            let location = touch.locationInNode(self)  

            print(camera!.containsNode(myLabel))  
            print(camera!.containedNodeSet())  

        }  
    }  

    override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {  
        / Called before each frame is rendered */  
    }  
}
```

The output in the log is:

```
false
[]
```

Shouldn't it be returning true and myLabel in the set since it's a node in the scene (and clearly visible)?
Is there something I'm doing wrong? Any help is appreciated!

*Just before someone says the simulator isn't accurate, I'm running this on an iPad mini 2.* :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this was a bug and Apple has recognized it in iOS 9 beta 3. I will edit my answer to confirm if it works.

EDIT: It works! Update your development device and it should work.

Comment: Still seeing this in iOS 9.3. Facepalm.